# fgets() not waiting for input

Tags: c, fgets

I wrote the following code:

```
int N;
scanf("%d", &N);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  char line[LINE_MAX];
  if (fgets(line, LINE_MAX, stdin) != NULL) {
    // do stuff with line here
    printf("%c - %c\n", line[0], line[1]);
  }
}
```

I have an input file which has the number of lines it has, and then that number of lines followed which I want to process. So I read in the number of lines into `N`. After that, I use `fgets` to get the line to be able to process it.

However, `fgets` does not seem to wait for a stdin the first time. I always get output of `-`, and then it waits for input. Meaning, the first iteration of the loop, it is not waiting for standard input at `fgets` and just prints out two empty characters separated by `-` as my `printf` does.

Why is that? How can I get `fgets` to wait for input each time? I feel like it is a threading issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As **geekosaur** said, you are not handling the newline left behind by `scanf`. You can modify your `scanf` format string to take it into account:

```
scanf("%d *[^\n]", &N);
```

`*[^\n]` says to ignore everything after your integer input that isn't a newline, but don't do anything with the newline (skip it).

Test program output:

```
emulawsk@cs:~/testing$ ./test2
3
13
1 - 3
26
2 - 6
59
5 - 9
```

Comment: But this does still leave the newline unread, which means it's the first thing read by the following `fgets()`, which is usually not what is intended.

Comment: You want `%*[^\n]` -- without the `%` it will try to match a literal `*`.  You also don't want the space -- it will just screw things up.

Answer (score 6):

You can place a call to `fflush()` just after the scanf() like this:

```
int N;
scanf("%d", &N);
fflush (stdin);
int i;
... (rest of code)...
```

So the newline character ges erased from the `stdin` buffer and the next `fgets()` will stop to ask for input.

Comment: Though provided by some implementations, fflush(stdin) is not a part of standard C and its behaviour for anything other than fflush(ostream) is undefined. Avoid it at all costs.

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with threading.  `scanf()` reads exactly what you ask it to; it's leaving everything else unread, notably the newline following the data.  (You also aren't dealing with the possibility that the user didn't type what you intended.)

If you want to do line oriented input, use `fgets()`.  Don't use `scanf()` and hope the system can magically intuit that you want to ignore what you didn't read.

Comment: I completely forgot about newline. Thanks

Comment: For some reason, I made a an array of char of size 1 to put the int there, so: `char Nc[1]` and `fgets(Nc, 1, stdin)` but again, `fgets` does not wait to read anything. The program just exists.

Comment: @Nayefc: You can still use scanf. See my answer.

Comment: @Nayefc: Yes, the program just exists, but I think you meant that it just *exits*.