# fgets executing before printf or scanf statement

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I'm fairly new to C and I have this program, and whenever I execute it, I get a weird output, like if fgets was bypassing and taking priority over printf and scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct object {
   float weight;
   char name[30];
   char utility[30]; 
};

int main()
{
    struct object *ptr;
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter the number of objects: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    ptr = (struct object*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct object));

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s\n", (ptr+i)->name);

        printf("Enter weight: ");
        scanf("%f\n", &(ptr+i)->weight);

        printf("Enter Utility: ");
        fgets((ptr+i)->utility, 30, stdin);
        (ptr+i)->utility[strlen((ptr+i)->utility)-1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("\nDisplaying Information:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("Name: %s\tUtility: %s\tWeight: %0.1f\n", (ptr+i)->name, (ptr+i)->utility, (ptr+i)->weight);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Enter the number of objects: 1   
Enter name: name
utility
Enter weight: Enter Utility: 
Displaying Information:
Name: name      Utility: utility        Weight: 0.0
```

I've tried what suggested in [fgets() not waiting for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156696/fgets-not-waiting-for-input) but nothing worked, even printing to stderr.

**EDIT:**
I've manage to fix it the following way. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct object {
   float weight;
   char name[30];
   char utility[30]; 
};

int main()
{
    struct object *ptr;
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter the number of objects: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    ptr = (struct object*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct object));

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", &ptr[i].name);

        printf("Enter weight: ");
        scanf("%f", &ptr[i].weight);

        while ((getchar()) != '\n');
        printf("Enter Utility: ");
        fgets(ptr[i].utility, 30, stdin);
        ptr[i].utility[strlen(ptr[i].utility)-1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("\nDisplaying Information:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("Name: %s\tUtility: %s\tWeight: %0.1f\n", ptr[i].name, ptr[i].utility, ptr[i].weight);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't mix your input methods (unless you are 100% conversant with their different foibles), and please see [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Comment: It might help to follow each prompt with `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: help yourself and use normal index notation  - for example `ptr[i].name;` Isn't it easier to read?

Comment: Having a `\n` in a scanf format doesn't do what you would expect it to do -- it waits for some non-whitespace to be entered.

Comment: WIth your code, you need to understand the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string.  When you remove that trailing white space, you need to understand that [`scanf()` leaves the newline character in the input buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/15168).  If you continue to mix `fgets()` with `scanf()`, you will need to be very careful.  You will do better to use `fgets()` to read all lines of input and then use `sscanf()` to parse the lines.  This is more reliable, and makes it much easier to give a coherent error report — and you can try converting several times.